# mod_rewrite: redirect to a folder with the same name as domain

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a bunch of domains pointing to the same folder, the root of my host "public_html".
I wish I could redirect them, each one for a folder with the same name as the domain.

eg: redirect www.mydomain.com to "public_html/www.mydomain.com"

I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/%{HTTP_HOST}/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L]
```

But with no success. What's wrong?
Its even possible to redirect to folder that uses a 'dot' on its name?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Your RewriteCond looks fishy - the "!" means negation, what you're saying is that you don't want the rewrite to apply to any request matching the host, a slash, and then ANY text, so as far as I can read it, you're effectively saying that no URL will match and thus the rule will never be applied.

Comment: What I tried to suggest is: if %{REQUEST_URI} NOT (!) ^/%{HTTP_HOST}/.*$ RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The test pattern in your RewriteCond is actually trying to match input starting with the *literal* string  `/%{HTTP_HOST}/`. The value of the `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable is not expanded like you were expecting, so the condition will always be true (the pattern itself will never match). You'll need to modify the RewriteCond, and there are a few different approaches.

If this is the only rewrite you perform, you can just check to see if you've done it yet:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
```

Or, if the resource won't exist until you rewrite it, you can check for that instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Finally, you can mimic your original condition by using backreferences within the test pattern, along with a separator character that won't appear in your URL:

```
RewriteCond /%{HTTP_HOST}/#%{REQUEST_URI} !^([^#]+)#\1
```

Note that this doesn't guarantee that you've done the redirection though, it only ensures that the request URI has the host name as its first path segment. However, that's generally good enough.

Comment: How could I expand the HTTP_HOST variable to use in the redirection? Is that possible or I have to explicitly write the conditions for each domain/folder?

Comment: @DenisBrat It'll expand itself in your replacement string, so there's no problem there; your RewriteRule should be fine as-is. mod_rewrite will just not expand variables within test patterns (they're compiled up front). Basically, you can use %{HTTP_HOST} (and other variables) on the left parameter to RewriteCond, and the right parameter to RewriteRule. Anywhere else will likely not work as you expect.

Comment: @Tim Stone for some reason, if i place RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !="" before last RewriteCond you send me, it does not work. However if I take if off, It works just fine! But now if I try to access a subfolder, it redirects my domain to www.mydomain.com/www.mydomain.com/subfolder. Its anything relationed to the test pattern?

Comment: @DenisBrat Ah, my mistake. The `!` should not have been there. Where did you expect the subfolder to go (what's wrong about that behaviour)?

Comment: If checking for file existence, `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` to check for directory existence is probably also desired.

Comment: @TimStone Now it works with the     RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ="". Currently, if I try to access a subfolder of the domain it redirects to http://www.mydomain.com/www.mydomain.com/subfolder. I wanted it to show only http://www.mydomain.com/subfolder not containing the folder the domain is pointing to. Is that possible? Thanks a lot for your attention

Comment: @DenisBrat Ah, it's externally redirecting. Does the URL it redirects to have a forward slash at the end? It sounds like mod_dir applying the [DirectorySlash](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) directive (which happens after your rewrite).

Comment: @TimStone If I add the slash in the end, it works. If I don't, it externally redirects and adds the slash. However if a file exists (index.php), it does not add the forward slash and works just fine. Thanks for your effort and attention!

Comment: @DenisBrat No problem. Hm, well you can perform the external redirect to add the slash up front so it won't try to do it for you, or you can turn off `DirectorySlash` directive and handle the folder -> index.php conversion to yourself. Each has its own pros and cons, I suppose.